# Не отправляются письма на хостинге

Tags: smtp, laravel-5.6

Всем привет, только начал изучать ларавел и сразу проблема.

Все очень коротко и просто.

1)
Создал новый проект
laravel new test1

2)
подключил регистрацию/авторизацию
php artisan make:auth
php artisan migrate

3)
настроил подключение к бд

4)
настроил подключение к почте smtp

5) сделал тест на локальном сервере: все вроде работает. Новый пользователь в базу записывается, потом если выйти можно и авторизоваться, пробую восстановить пароль, тоже работает, приходит письмо на почту с ссылкой на восстановление пароля

6) тест на хостинге:
переношу все на хостинг, все настраиваю точно так же. К бд подключение есть. При регистрации все записывается, а при попытке восстановления пароля выдает ошибку

"Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]"

это в env.php

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Помогите решить эту проблему пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

> Connection timed out

Скрипт не может установить соединение с сервером smtp.gmail.com:465 за указанное время. 
Скорей всего на вашем хостинге установлен запрет на исходящие соединения на порт 465. Возможно оператор хостинга борется таким образом с рассылками спама, а может не учитывает, что почтовые сервера могут быть не только на 25 порту.

В любом случае вам надо выяснить у оператора хостинга возможность отправки почты через сторонние сервера.

Comment: хостингу я уже писал, и получил следующий ответ, я его не очень понимаю, но выглядит как будто они говорят что все ок работает у них   (ДАЛЕЕ ИХ ОТВЕТ) Здравствуйте.
Коннект работает, IP-адрес сервера не заблокирован. Никаких проблем быть не должно:
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying 64.233.165.109...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com (64.233.165.109).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP u19-v6sm390851lje.51 - gsmtp
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection u19-v6sm390851lje.51 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: "telnet smtp.gmail.com 25" как я и предполагал, работает соединение на 25 порт. А вы соединяетесь на 465-й. Надо проверять "telnet smtp.gmail.com 465"

Comment: написал им, подождем ответа....

Answer (score 0):

С хостинга прислали

## > Вот требования google smtp:

```
SMTP Server : smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Username: Your full Gmail username (email address), for example youremail@gmail.com
SMTP Password: Your Gmail password.
SMTP Port: 587
TLS/SSL: Required.
```

===
Проверяем порт 587:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 64.233.164.109...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com (64.233.164.109).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP t2-v6sm1584119ljj.46 - gsmtp
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection t2-v6sm1584119ljj.46 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```